# Download/Export complete Dataset of WFS with limited amount of features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, wfs, merge

I want to export a WFS Dataset with over 14.000 Features in it. The Amount of features one can download is limited to 300.

Is there any way to extract all features to one shapefile in QGIS, even if the amount of features is limited? I am thinking of an algorithm that exports the features in small amount < 300 (in a small area) and merges them at the end.

Comment: Enable paging, for the WFS source set paging size to 300, select the feature type.  All features will be downloaded (300 at a time).  Export as shapefile